# OCI runtime(container_linux.go:348) error in docker

Tags: docker

my Server is :

```
3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
```

and my docker version is :

> Docker version 18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1

I got this error after my simple code `docker run hello-world` why ?

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:297: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused \"write
>   init-p: broken pipe\"": unknown.

Comment: I've seen this issue with kernel versions 3.x and solved it updating it to 4.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find solution , and i want to share it, If you’re using Docker CE on Ubuntu, take Docker back one patch version (if you’re on Debian, replace debian for ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
```

If you’re using Docker EE, you can downgrade with something like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ee=18.09.1~ee-0~ubuntu
```

For Docker CE on CentOS 7 (Docker EE and/or Fedora are similar):

```
$ sudo curl -SsL https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
$ sudo yum --showduplicates list docker-ce
$ sudo yum install docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3-0.el7.centos
```

Answer (score 2):

recently encountered similar problem
just updated the linux kernel from 3.x version to 4.x version

```
$ apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

then try docker run commands

to know the current linux kernel version

```
$ uname -a
```